# Resharper not running NUnit tests

Tags: unit-testing, nunit, resharper, visual-studio-2013, specflow

I'm using VS2013 Professional with Resharper 8.1
I have a project which has all the tests, some of them are made with MSTest and most of them are NUnit tests. However, since I installed Resharper 8.1, the NUnit tests don't run anymore when I click the "Run all tests" button. I have to go to the resharper menu and select Unit Tests -> Run All Tests from Solution. Or if I want to see the coverage, it doesn't work if I click the "Cover all tests with dotCover", I have to go to Resharper -> Unit tests -> Cover all tests from solution.
Here's a screenshot: http://prntscr.com/2bkizm
The BDD folder has 4 SpecFlow scenarios which use MSTest. The Unit Tests folder has NUnit tests, and those aren't run when I click one of those buttons. Do you know why is this happening? I already tried reinstalling an older version of Resharper, but it doesn't work. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Resharper 8.0, the functionality of `Run all tests` is only to run all tests that are currently in the test session, i.e. the window. If you use `Run all tests from solution` it creates a new tab with all tests from your solution in it and runs all of those.
Looking at the release notes for 8.1 (http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2013/12/resharper-81-goes-rtm-along-with-dotcover-dottrace/) there is no hint that this this functionality will change.

Comment: I think it'a a bug, because sometimes it runs all the tests, and sometimes it doesn't. But the button for "Cover all tests with dotCover" only runs the MSTest ones.
Here's a new screenshot:
http://prntscr.com/2bsp3f
I will report this to JetBrains

Comment: Have you configured your SpecFlow tests to use MSTest or are they defaulting to NUnit?

Comment: I configured them to use MSTest, because I had some problems with NUnit. The project is for a Windows Phone app, so I have a PCL library with the app logic, a WP project for the app, and a PCL project with all the tests. I made a request on JetBrains for this issue: http://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/requests/5264

Also, I made a gif when I was running the tests, so if you want to see this bug in action, watch this gif: http://gifti.me/image/WuH